# Dynamic name of item in array jQuery

Tags: jquery, dynamic

I have codes :

```
line:1       var listInput = $('input.model');
line:2       var listVariable = [];
line:3       $.each(listInput, function (index, val) {      
line:4             var variable = $(val).data('name');
line:5             var valOf = $(val).val();
line:6             var item = { variable : valOf };
line:7             listVariable.push(item);
line:8       });
```

I want the "variable" in line 6 that is the "variable" in line 4

Please help me, sorry about my english.

Comment: Remove `line:1` from code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [Bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation) to populate `item`'s property using dynamic key.

```
$.each(listInput, function (index, val) {      
    var item = {}; //Create object
    item[$(val).data('name')] = $(val).val(); //Set the value
    listVariable.push(item);
});
```

OR, You can use `.map()` along with `.get()`

```
var listVariable = listInput.map(function(){
    var item = {};
    item[$(this).data('name')] = $(this).val();     
    return item;
}).get();
```